# React Router - Ignore / Redirect to subfolder

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router, react-router-dom

Is it possible to ignore a specific URL in the react router?

I have an app for a service desk app in a subdir which I can not reach, once I have entered the react app.

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  component={ViewHome}
/>

<Route
  path="/about"
  component={ViewAbout}
/>

<Route
  path="/help"
  // Ignore the React App and forward this request to the server.
/>
```

As Marvin stated in his answer, this could be a server config problem. Here is the content of the .htaccess rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(help)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your question, but this sounds like a server configuration issue.

For example, I use Nginx on my server to configure the router.
The usual behavior of your browser is to search for a subdirectory when you do /something.

But if you configure it in a way that your servers keeps looking at your index file it should be fine.

What works for me in my Nginx config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be right. Since Apache is running on my machine, I have to search the htaccess. I'll update the question.